# if $x,y \in\mathbb Z $ prove through contrapositive that $x+y\geqslant 1$ then $x\geqslant 1$ or $y\geqslant 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have reached the part of: 
 
$x<1 \wedge y<1 \implies x+y<1$ 
I am struggling with how to prove that since $x,y\in Z$ then $x+y<1$ since the largest integer after 1 is 0. Can I explain this mathematically or is it fine if i just write it down like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x <1$ implies that $x \leq 0$. Similarly, $y \leq 0$. Hence $x+y \leq 0+0=0$ and hence $x+y <1$.